# How to check which instance of child control is used in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have two usercontrols : ParentUserControl.xaml and ChildUserControl.xaml

**ParentUserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DemoSilverlight.ParentUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:DemoSilverlight"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
            Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <sdk:TabControl x:Name="tabControlHeatMapEditor" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="tabControlHeatMapEditor_SelectionChanged" Height="510" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12">
            <sdk:TabItem Header="Original Heat Map" x:Name="tabItemOriginalHeatMap">
                <Local:ChildUserControl x:Name="chartControlOriginal"/>
            </sdk:TabItem>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="Revised Heat Map" x:Name="tabItemRevisedHeatMap">
                <Local:ChildUserControl x:Name="chartControlRevised"/>
            </sdk:TabItem>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="Compare Original/Revised" x:Name="tabItemCompareOrgRev">
                <!--<Local:ChildUserControl x:Name="chartControlCompare"/>-->
            </sdk:TabItem>
        </sdk:TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Inside the ChildUserControl control I have a button control. In the code behind page of the 
ChildUserControl.xaml.cs, I want to know which instance of the ChildUserControl is used and based on that I want to access the button within the ChildUserControl in order to make it disabled.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0):

Have a enum in ChildUserControl. Based on TabItem Selection set the enum property and further based on your condition you can either enable or disable the button.